# I having trouble to solve a function that can give me the number of subArrays in A that can sum for K

Tags: c

The complexity of my question is **O(n*log(n))**, it could be cool if you guys use division and conquer to solve this, so I can learn more about the algorithm. So far I have done this:

```
int division(int *num, int low, int high, int k, int n, int count) {
    if (low == high)
        return num[low];
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    int lsum = division(num, low, mid, k, n, count);
    int rsum = division(num, mid + 1, high, k, n, count);
     
    if (lsum == k)
        count++;
    if (rsum == k)
        count++;
    if ((lsum + rsum) == k)
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

I am trying to solve this question from my list in college, but I can't find any content about this problem and I am having problem solving this.

**UPDATE:**
I found this method, i am trying to find the maximum number of possible sum of subarrays including zero values, i approach a recursive tree method but it cant work with zero values(lembrar is equal to remember in portuguese as valor is equal to value and acumulo is equal to counter):

```
int soma(int valor,int*numeros,int tamanho,int* lembrar){
    
    if(valor==0)
        return 1;
    if(valor<0)
        return 0;
    if(lembrar[valor] != -1)
        return lembrar[valor];
        
    int acumulo=0;
    for(int i=0;i<tamanho;i++)
    {
    
        int target = valor - numeros[i];
        int result = soma(target,numeros,tamanho,lembrar);
        acumulo += result;
        lembrar[target] = result;
    }
    
    lembrar[valor] = acumulo;
    return acumulo;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "subArray"?

Comment: When you say "subArray", are you talking about any multi-subset of the elements, are are you only considering consecutive sequences of elements?  If the array is 1, 3, 2, and the desired sum is 3, would {1, 2} count?  I'm guessing not, since I don't think it could be solved in O(n*log(n)) time unless the sequences were consecutive.

Comment: What is `igual` ? Where did that come from?

Comment: Also, are the array elements constrained to be greater than 0?  Or are negative and/or zero values allowed?

Comment: Is the array guaranteed to be sorted? Upd: Actually, that's irrelevant since an array can be sorted in O(N log N).

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- The array only contains non-negative values.<sup>[1]</sup>
- The desired sum is positive.
- The order of the element doesn't matter (e.g. the count for array [1,k-1,k] and target k is 2).

One approach:

1. Set the count to zero.
2. Sort the array. [O(n log n)]<sup>[2]</sup>
3. Use a sliding window to find the subarrays: [O(n)]

   1. Set the sum to zero.
   2. Point start to the first element.
   3. Point end to the first element.
   4. Loop,

      1. If the sum is equal to the target sum,

         1. Set the number of zeroes to zero.
         2. While the value of the element at start is zero, and while start doesn't point beyond the end of the array,

            1. Increment the number of zeroes.
            2. Increment start.
         3. Increment the counter by the square of the number of zeroes (`((size_t)1) << z`).
         4. Set the operation to perform to grow.<sup>[3]</sup>
      2. Else,

         1. If the sum is greater than the target sum,

            1. Set the operation to perform to shrink.
         2. Else,

            1. Set the operation to perform to grow.
      3. If the operation to perform is shrink,

         1. Subtract the value referenced by start from the sum.
         2. Increment start.
      4. Else,

         1. If end points beyond the end of the array,

            1. Exit the loop.
         2. Add the value referenced by end to the sum.
         3. Increment end.

---

Footnotes:

1. It may be possible to support negative values. I did not study this.
2. This operation can be skipped if the array is already sorted, reducing the solution from O(n log n) to O(n).
3. Ultimately, we want to both shrink and grow. And they can be done in any order. By sticking to one of the two per loop pass, we can eliminate the whole "operation to perform" variable without redundant code by reordering the code a little. (Not done above.)

Comment: So, i was searching some other way to answer that question and i found it, but it doenst work with zero values, i dont know if is missing something in the code or the method i use simply can not take zero values (sorry my bad english):

Comment: ok? So use my approach. It does support zeroes in the array.

Comment: Your code is working but is not giving ALL the combinations with zero, if i put in the array: [0,7,0] this will give me 3 possibilites when i really want 4 possibilities: [7],[0,7],[7,0],[0,7,0]

Comment: oh, that's easy to fix. We want to increment the counter by 2^z instead of by z+1 (where z = number of zeroes) when sum == target. Done.